# Stored procedure inserting twice MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE c_ranges(
    _nombre VARCHAR(100),
    _limiteinferior DECIMAL(10,2),
    _limitesuperior DECIMAL(10,2)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _newID INT;
    SELECT MAX(idrango)+1 FROM rango INTO _newID;
    IF (_newID IS NULL) THEN
        SET _newID = 0;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO rango (idrango,nombre,limiteinferior,limitesuperior)
    VALUES(_newID,_nombre,_limiteinferior,_limitesuperior);
    SELECT idrango FROM rango WHERE idrango=_newID;
END //
```

And when I run it like this:

```
CALL c_ranges("My range",0,10.3)
```

It inserts the same record twice, but the second with the id increased by one.

This is content of the table after several attempts of inserts using the stored procedure.

First attempt: `call c_Ranges("first range",0,0)`

Second attempt: `call c_Ranges("second range",0,0)`

Third attempt: `call c_Ranges("third range",0,0)`

[image]

I'm really disconcerted, can someone tell me what could be happening?

Comment: i have tested it on my local ..its working fine .May be you have executed twice by mistakely

Comment: Ankit Agrawal, I don't think so, I have did it maybe 30 different times, I'm guessing that could be phpMyAdmin, but for today I'm done, 10 hours of constant work is too much for me. Anyways, thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: It is not related to your problem, but you can optimize you  procedure by setting idrango as auto-increment then you edit your procedure as : BEGIN
    INSERT INTO rango (nombre,limiteinferior,limitesuperior)
    VALUES(_nombre,_limiteinferior,_limitesuperior);
    SELECT idrango FROM rango order by idrango desc limit 1 ;
END

Comment: Thank you, Imanez, I'll consider your advice.

Comment: do you call this procedure for a code or you execute it manually in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Manually, that's why I think it's a problem with PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: My PHPMyAdmin version is 4.0.10deb1 and I have similar issue when running `CALL aStoredProc()` in SQL command input of PhpMyAdmin. It call them twice causing two records created. This issue does not happen if you execute from PhpMyAdmin->Database->Routine->Execute or from MySQL command line.

Comment: Indeed the problem was phpMyAdmin, 100% tested.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to that situation recently. What happened to me was that the method on my code which call the stored procedure was executing twice because of my own logic. I know, it's stupid but it was!
My validation evaluates the result of stored procedure response and according to this I manage the flow retrieving an empty JSON or the responsed one. My mistake was run the method twice instead of storing the response and after run the validation. It was something like this...

What I did wrong...

```
return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.callProcedure("copyData")) ? "{}" : data.callProcedure("copyData"));
```

What I should have done!

```
string response = data.callProcedure("copyData");
return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) ? "{}" : response));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Cause: phpMyAdmin issue

As noted by @ZamronyP.Juhara in [a comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135113/stored-procedure-inserting-twice-mysql#comment79795923_43135113), this can happen …

> when running `CALL aStoredProc()` in SQL command input of PhpMyAdmin. It call them twice causing two records created. This issue does not happen if you execute from PhpMyAdmin->Database->Routine->Execute or from MySQL command line.

I just encountered this behaviour while testing a stored procedure via phpMyAdmin 4.0.4.2.